Selenium python scraping more button for profiles
im trying to scrape linkedin profiles - to press the button more but i cannot seem to suceed at it
I tried many ways, one of them being -
def click_more_actions_button(driver):
    try:
        # Wait for the "More actions" button to be clickable
        more_actions_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@aria-label='More']"))
        )
        # Click the "More actions" button
        more_actions_button.click()
        print("Clicked on the 'More' button.")
        
        # Wait for the dropdown to appear
        WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "ember3150"))
        )
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error clicking 'More' button: {e}")

but i cannot get to make it to find that button and click on it. Has anyone ever done it? Im trying to get to press message to send an inmail
I tried different selectors and i expected to get the more button to open up so i can send a message
